# Electron: How to resize the BrowserWindow?

Tags: node.js, npm, window, electron, node-webkit

How to change the size of the BrowserWindow, not at startup, but on time work?

All the solutions that I found were about such:

```
var win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600, show: false });
```

Answer (score 14):

Do you mean after the BrowserWindow is created you want to change its size dynamically. You can use setSize

```
win.setSize(width, height[, animate])
```

Refer [docs](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/browser-window/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the setSize method, you should also use `.center` afterwards to prevent any unnecessary movement after the change

```
// width, height, animate (true or false)
win.setSize(300, 200, faldse)
win.center()
```